# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException bad array lengths at Cloudinary OnProgress method

Tags: android, cloudinary

I am having a very small amount of users crash on a specific device version when trying to upload to Cloudinary service to reduce video size. They crash with the following error -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
bad array lengths
```

I can’t seem to reproduce the bug on my device, and it does not seem to occur anymore. here is the entire trace -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
bad array lengths
android.os.Parcel.readIntArray (Parcel.java:905)
android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag (INotificationManager.java:732)
android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:230)
android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify (NotificationManagerCompat.java:212)
android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify (NotificationManagerCompat.java:196)
com.onemdtalent.app.util.CloudinaryListenerService.onProgress (CloudinaryListenerService.java:80)
com.cloudinary.android.DefaultCallbackDispatcher$1.handleMessage (DefaultCallbackDispatcher.java:66)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5740)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:905)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

here is the relevant OnProgress method -

```
 @Override
    public void onProgress(String requestId, long bytes, long totalBytes) {
        int x = 5 / 0;
        if (totalBytes > 0) {
            double progressFraction = (double) bytes / totalBytes;
            int progress = (int) Math.round(progressFraction * 1000);
            mBuilder.setProgress(1000, ((100 / 3) * 2) * 10 + (progress / 3), false); //include compress and storage progress components to final progress calculation
            mBuilder.setContentText(String.format("Uploading video: %d%% (%d KB)", (int) ((((100 / 3) * 2) * 10 + (progress / 3)) * 0.1), bytes / 1024));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setProgress(1000, 1000, true);
            mBuilder.setContentText(String.format("%d KB", bytes / 1024));
            onError(new Throwable("Something wrong with file. "));
        }
        mManagerCompat.notify(NOTI_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

I have searched for the past 2 days on this bug and it seems like a bug related to the operating system without any known fixes. If anyone can highlight any clue to what may cause the issue I would be happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

It's Shirly from Cloudinary :)
If that happened again, can you please contact us with timestamps and the Cloud name for further investigation?
Thanks!